# Is tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell a single LSTM unit or a LSTM layer?

Tags: tensorflow

in the tensorflow, there is a lstm implementation called `BasicLSTMCell` which at `tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell`. And it has a parameter `num_units` which means the number of units in the LSTM cell. But I do not know what that means.

If I define  a lstm cell like this:

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(512).
```

what does the lstm_cell look like? It is a lstm node or a lstm layer with 512 node??Who can tell me about this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an LSTM layer with` 512 units.

`BasicLSTMCell` implements the abstract class `RNNCell`. From the documentation:

> Abstract object representing an RNN cell.
>
> Every RNNCell must have the properties below and implement `call` with the signature `(output, next_state) = call(input, state)`.
>
> [...]
>
> This definition of cell differs from the definition used in the literature. In the literature, 'cell' refers to an object with a single scalar output. **This definition refers to a horizontal array of such units**.

A common way of creating the LSTM layer together with the unrolling for Back Propagation Trough Time is the following one:

```
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(512)
outputs, final_state = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell=lstm_cell,
                           dtype=tf.float32,
                           inputs=some_input_sequence)
```

where:

- `some_input_sequence` is a list of `num_steps` tensors of size `[batch_size, input_size]`
- `outputs` will contain the output of the layer after each of the elements of `some_input_sequence`. So it is again a list of `num _steps` elements of size `[batch_size, 512]` (where 512 was the number of units of your cell)
- `final_state` will contain the state after the entire sequence has been processed. In particular, for LSTM, it is a named tuple with two elements, `c` and `h` (the two states of a LSTM).